# Android Studio 1.0 does not open

Tags: android, windows, ide

I owned an old version of Android Studio Beta and was working fine!
My Windows 7 is 64-bit. With the JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME variables set.
This version of Android Studio Beta was running on 32-bit because the android64.exe not open, had no error. I tried to run even as administrator.
I bent and installed the 1.0 version of Android Studio and began my problems ... none of Android Studio opens.
When you try to open any of the Android Studio on 32-bit displays the error window:

> "We have detected That You are running the 64-bit version of the Windows operating system Please run studio64.exe instead..."

When trying to run studio64.exe shows no window and no open Android Studio including as administrator.

Comment: Do you have the latest JRE version installed? Not sure what is the requirement for Android Studio 1.0 in relation to this but it's worth to check

Comment: Windows

Microsoft® Windows® 8/7/Vista/2003 (32 or 64-bit)
2 GB RAM minimum, 4 GB RAM recommended
400 MB hard disk space + at least 1 G for Android SDK, emulator system images, and caches
1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution
Java Development Kit (JDK) 7
Optional for accelerated emulator: Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality

Comment: I checked and I am with the minimum requirements. Still do not believe that Android Studio 1.0 has "damaged" the Beta before that worked in 32 bits.

Comment: What about event viewer? Have you checked to see if there is any error logged that could help to understand why it crashes in silence?

Comment: I'm sorry .... now you got me I have no idea how to do this ... I knew the .bat in beta showing me the error. I tried to do it but does not log errors. In 1.0 does not have the .bat.

Answer (score 0):

install latest jdk 8  and go to my computer propertties > advanced system settings > advanced > environment variables > new >variable name> java_home > variable value> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25

Comment: Installed Java 8 and did not work, continue with the same problems!